# EF4 STE's many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco

Could anyone point me in the right direction with this issue I am having. Essentially I have a many to many relationship that when I call SaveChanges() the join table never gets populated. ReferenceData is a generated POCO and referenceDataSets is a List. Essentially this data is transmitted via USB Key. context is the DBContext of the destination database.

```
foreach (ReferenceData refSet in referenceDataSets)
            {
                // check if the reference data set already exists
                ReferenceData existing = context.ReferenceDatas
                    .Include("ReferenceDataValues")
                    .Where(o => o.Name == refSet.Name)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

                // if reference data set already exists
                if (existing != null)
                {
                    while (existing.ReferenceDataValues.Count > 0)
                    {
                        context.ReferenceDataValues.DeleteObject(existing.ReferenceDataValues[0]);
                    }
                    while (refSet.ReferenceDataValues.Count > 0)
                    {
                        existing.ReferenceDataValues.Add(refSet.ReferenceDataValues[0]);
                    }
                    context.ReferenceDatas.ApplyChanges(existing);
                }
                else
                {
                    //if this reference dataset doesnt exist
                    //issue exists here as many to many does not get populated.
                    context.ReferenceDatas.AddObject(refSet);              
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Any help much appreciated.
Jay

Comment: What do you mean by "Essentially this data is transmitted via USB Key. "?

Comment: Serialised as XML but the crux of the issue is why EF is not generating the join table insert statements.